# After running for few days if mysql gives following error

Tags: networking, server, mysql

After running perfectly for few days, If the mysql server gives following error.

```
mysql -uroot -p -h localhost
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket 
'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Comment: Please edit your post to clearly include your specific question in the body of the qyestion. Have your question also reflected in the title.

Answer (score 0):

Then please do followings

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo rm /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0
sudo rm /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1
sudo service mysql restart
sudo service mysql restart
```